# Nginx with only TLS1.3 cipher suites

Tags: openssl, nginx

I am trying to configure Nginx to use only TLS1.3 with 2 ciphers: **TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256.**

So, I tried this configuration:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256;
```

But **nginx -s reload** errors out with

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256") failed (SSL: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match)", "operationName": "Default", "category": "Default"}
```

Looks like I need to append at least one non-TLS1.3 cipher to make the config work. I tried various such combinations and they worked. One of them is:

```
TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Why is it so? I think it's happening because OpenSSL itself doesn't accept the original ciphersuite string. I am using OpenSSL-1.1.1g.

```
root@2ed6cae6e062:/azure/appgw# openssl ciphers -v TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
Error in cipher list
140686067873536:error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:ssl/ssl_lib.c:2558:
```

There are some useful links I came across but couldn't figure out how to achieve what I want - **using only TLS1.3 ciphersuites**.

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,284909,284914#msg-284914
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1529
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Ciphersuites

Comment: Specifying at least one 1.2 (or lower) cipher in the `ssl_ciphers` directive 'works' in the sense of not giving an error, but it doesn't do what you want: it has no effect on the suites used for 1.3. The ticket you link describes the workaround, using (instead) OpenSSL's configuration file.

Comment: TLS 1.3 does not allow you to specify specific cipher suits as far as I know. Why do you want only these two?

Comment: @MechMK1, because the two is more secure than the other.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the provided links. All the answers by Maxim Dounin are valuable. You should provide a cipher that makes `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` happy and then force the list of ciphers using the `ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites` directive.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```

OpenSSL version :

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Note that TLSv1.3 ciphers are enabled by default.

```
# openssl ciphers -v ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

Using a script proposed at https://superuser.com/a/224263 and particularly the updated version at https://gist.github.com/jahir/23c4202eee12e377ef3acf1dcdc7c776 I checked the above configuration.

```
$ ./test_ciphers.sh <put IP here>:443
Using OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021.
Using tls1_1
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA         ... NO (tlsv1 alert protocol version)
...
Using tls1_2
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  ... NO (tlsv1 alert protocol version)
...
Using tls1_3
Testing TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384         ... YES
Testing TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ... YES
Testing TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256         ... YES
```

Script included below for reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CIPHERS='ALL:eNULL'
DELAY=${2:-0.1}
SERVER=${1:?usage: $0 <host:port> [delay, default is ${DELAY}s] [ciphers, default is ${CIPHERS}]}
MAXLEN=$(openssl ciphers "$CIPHERS" | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '{ if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}')

echo Using $(openssl version).

declare -A TLSMAP=( [tls1_1]=cipher [tls1_2]=cipher [tls1_3]=ciphersuites )

for tlsver in "${!TLSMAP[@]}"
do
  echo "Using $tlsver"
  ciphers=$(openssl ciphers -$tlsver -s "$CIPHERS" | sed -e 's/:/ /g')
  for cipher in ${ciphers[@]}
  do
    in=$(openssl s_client -$tlsver -${TLSMAP[$tlsver]} "$cipher" -connect $SERVER </dev/null 2>&1)
    if [[ "$in" =~ ":error:" ]] ; then
      result="NO ($(echo -n $in | cut -d':' -f6))"
    else
      if [[ "$in" =~ "Cipher is ${cipher}" || "$in" =~ "Cipher    :" ]] ; then
        result='YES'
      else
        result="UNKNOWN RESPONSE\n$in"
      fi
    fi
    printf 'Testing %-*s ... %s\n' "$MAXLEN" "$cipher" "$result"
    sleep $DELAY
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by adding `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;` directive.

Comment: The idea is to do just the exact opposite and enforce ciphers.

Comment: Maybe you meant using it with `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3` without v1.2. In that case that maybe ok per https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/. I have not tested it.

Comment: My bad. `off` is [recommended by Mozilla](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) and in fact means that the client will be able to choose the cipher _among_ the ones proposed by the server. Cfr. https://github.com/mozilla/server-side-tls/issues/260. But that means that the `ssl_protocols` and the `ssl_ciphers` must be carefully chosen.